# Verbose trendline calculation

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following data:

| date | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 1 |

I want to be able to calculate the trendline in a verbose manner, as in, "Positive" or "Negative."

How would I go about achieving that in Google Sheets?

Assuming I'd use y=mx+b, I used the SLOPE formula to find M, and then INTERCEPT to find Y. I don;t know where to go from here.

Comment: So basically it looks like you want to compare the previous value from `count` with the next value and get a result saying if the comparison was positive or negative, is that correct? For example, compare 5 with 2 and the result would be positive as it increased from one value to the next one, but when comparing 6 with 1 the result would be positive because it decreased.

Comment: I have the same request for clarification as Fernando- just that I think there are some 
(copy-paste) errors in their last sentence.  I'm assuming 6 -> 1 should get "negative"? Can you please create a markup table to show what the expected result should look like?